# How can I filter for multiple packages in Package Manager

Tags: packages, miktex, installing

I had to reinstall MiKTeX today and installing all packages i need took way too much time.

Is there a way to filter for multiple packages in the Package Manager?

I tried using `OR`, `,`, `;` and whitespace as seperator but nothing helped.

I would save a lot of time if I could select all packages I need at once or simply start a script which installs the packages I need.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance,

Felix

Comment: Okay scripting seems easy using `mpm --install=<package-name>`.

Comment: Just an idea: you could set `Install missing packages on-the-fly` to `Yes` (in `MiKTeX options`), then create a document which loads all the packages you want to install. When you compile it, everything should be installed automatically.

Comment: If you have found a working solution, feel free to answer your own question. You will not be able to formally accept the answer before a couple of days, but it will be useful nonetheless.

Comment: thanks for your ideas.

Yes the `install on-the-fly` option is useful but unfortunately it doesn't work in my case.

My comment isn't a answer to my question but kind of a workaround. If no answer is posted in a few days i will post it again with a simple working script and accept it as answer.

Comment: I don't see how such a filter would help you for a long list of packages. It is probably faster to go through the list and select a number of package and click on install. If you have a list of package you want to install in a file and use `mpm --install-some=FILE`

Comment: If you still have access to previous miktex installation can use `mpm` to import all packages from the previous one. `mpm --import-all --repository=DIR` (please, look at MikTeX help)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not answer my question but solves my problem.

The command line tool MiKTeX package manager (`mpm`) seems to be the best way to install multiple packages at once.

Espacially the commands

- `mpm --install-some=FILE` and
- `mpm --import-all --repository=DIR`

are very helpful when reinstalling MiKTeX.

For a documentation of the `mpm` program visit:
http://docs.miktex.org/manual/mpm.html

Thanks to Ulrike Fischer and Ignasi for your help.

However, this requires a bit of a technical understanding and the usage of the command line. For people who only use the windowed package manager, it would be good to have the ability to filter for multiple packages.

Comment: but can you use mpm to install multiple packages in one command? I'm not sure that you can. I tried 'mpm --install a b c', and it didn't work. I could only do a single pack